# Install MySQLdb (for python) as non-compressed egg

Tags: python, installation, mysql, egg

The install instructions are:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install # or su first
```

This gives me an .egg file. How do I tell the install to dump the files as a normal, uncompressed library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I hate to answer my own question, but:

find your python site-packages (mine is /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages )

then:

```
$ unzip MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.5-linux-i686.egg
```

This worked fine for me

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question on here. As long as you're contributing to knowledge base it's a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to this party, but here's a way to do it that seems to work great:

```
sudo python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/
```

And then you don't use a .python-egg, any *.pth files etc.

Answer (score 3):

From the  [EasyInstall](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#command-line-options) doc, command line options:

> --always-unzip, -Z
>
> Don't install any packages as zip files, even if the packages are marked as safe for running as a zipfile.

Can you use *easyinstall* instead of calling setup.py ?

calling  `easy_install -Z mysql_python` from the command prompt, finds the egg on the net and installs it.

Answer (score 1):

This will tell setuptools to not zip it up:

```
sudo python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed
```